# OSV method's return statement

Tags: python, odoo

In OpenERP, an OSV object can return something which can open a new view or activate an action. For instance, `sale.order` has `manual_invoice` method which returns the following:

```
    return {
        'name': _('Customer Invoices'),
        'view_type': 'form',
        'view_mode': 'form',
        'view_id': [res_id],
        'res_model': 'account.invoice',
        'context': "{'type':'out_invoice'}",
        'type': 'ir.actions.act_window',
        'nodestroy': True,
        'target': 'current',
        'res_id': inv_ids and inv_ids[0] or False,
    }
```

and it opens an invoice form view in the same window.

I've seen `'view_id': [res_id],` being changed to `'views': [(id2, 'form')],` and other parts also modified, and it still works.

So what I don't understand is how does this mechanism works. What determines which values in a return dict should be included? How can I know which ones are mandatory and which are not?

Many thanks!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The returned dictionary is interpreted as an action (`ir.actions.act_window` model), such as the ones found on XML views. The documentation is available in the [Technical Memento](http://doc.openerp.com/memento/OpenERP_Technical_Memento_v0.6.4.pdf) and in the [official docs](http://doc.openerp.com/v6.0/developer/2_7_menu_action/7_2_actions.html#window-action).

Comment: The only exception on this is the views attribute, which is a list with tuples whereas in the xml file you would have to create separate ir.actions.act_window.view records, perhaps its worth editing this in?

Comment: @Red15 In fact the `views` value that can be returned in such an inline action definition is not different from the actual function field `views` that exists on the ir.actions.act_window model. That function indeed relies on the `ir.actions.act_window.view` child records that specifies explicitly the views to use, but not only. And its value is the same list of tuples -- One difference I can think of is the availability of an extra `res_id` key that allows specifying the ID of a particular record to open, typically when the only enabled view is a form view. This is useful to (re)open wizards.