# openerp context in act_window

Tags: python, odoo

In OpenERP 6.1 this act_window:

```
<act_window
     domain="[('id', '=', student)]"
     id="act_schedule_student"
     name="Student"
     res_model="school.student"
     src_model="school.schedule"/>
```

creates a **Student** button in the **Schedule** form which opens the student tree view showing only the appropriate student.

My goal is to directly open the corresponding form view of the student instead of a tree view with the right filtered student.  I tried adding a `view_mode="form,tree"` but it opens a new form instead of the one I want. I'm guessing this can possibly be achieved by adding `context` to the `act_window`?  Maybe a `record_id`, but I tried that with `active_id` and it didn't work.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

The magical (and probably undocumented) way to have an OpenERP action directly open the form view of a given record, is to set an extra `res_id` attribute on the action.

Unfortunately in OpenERP 6.1<sup>[1]</sup> the `res_id` attribute is not part of the `act_window` data model, so it is not possible to directly set it in an XML declaration.

Most official addons use a `<button type="object" ... />` bound to a Python method that sets the `res_id` attribute in the returned action. It is quite easy to find examples of this in the source code of official modules, and you can see one [in this related question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10671025/osv-methods-return-statement).

**Quick/untested example:**

You would add this in your `school.schedule` form:

```
<button name="open_student_form" type="object" string="Student"/>
```

And the following method in the `school.schedule` model:

```
def open_student_form(self, cr, uid, ids, context=None):
    this = self.browse(cr, uid, ids, context=context)[0]
    return {
        'type': 'ir.actions.act_window',
        'name': 'Student',
        'view_mode': 'form',
        'view_type': 'form',
        'res_model': 'school.student',
        'nodestroy': 'true',
        'res_id': this.student.id, # assuming the many2one is (mis)named 'student'
        'views': [(False, 'form')],
    }
```

Now if you really wanted to do this with a "sidebar button" (i.e. with an `<act_window/>`), it gets a bit trickier because you cannot directly bind a sidebar button to a Python method; it must be bound to an action that is stored in the database.
It is still doable though, for example via an `ir.actions.server` action that can be bound to your `<act_window/>` and calls your Python method or does something similar. The trick with `ir.actions.server` is that it can be defined as a Python block that can return a dynamic action definition by assigning an action dictionary to an `action` variable.
If you want to follow that path, search the OpenERP addons source code for declarations of `ir.actions.server` (some of them might do similar things) and methods returning actions with a `res_id` attribute.

<sup>[1]</sup> As of OpenERP 7.0 the `res_id` column is explicitly available in the data model, so you can directly set it.

Comment: what does it mean when i get "cannot marshal recursive dictionaries" when clicking on the button?

Comment: @3a2roub: sounds like you're returning an incorrect action dict that contains a reference cycle, and the RPC serialization cannot transmit that on the wire. Look for typos in your code, the returned dict should only contain literal values. BTW watch out for the typo I fixed in my example: the ``res_id`` value must be an integer, so it should be ``this.student.id``, if ``this.student`` is a many2one relationship.

Comment: sorry this is turning out to be quite a nuisance. this works fine in the web client, but causes the gtk to crash. it will exit whenever i click the button. wouldnt even show an error in the console nor the openerp-client.exe.log. any clue?

Comment: if anyone's interested, turns out i hadn't added "nodestroy: true" in the function's return dict. it was needed for the button of type  bject. thanks odony.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

You can give domain in action itself. Whenever student clicks that menu, action will get trigger and there set the domain as following sample code:

```
<record id="action_id" model="ir.actions.act_window" >
         <field name="name">Sample</field>
         <field name="res_model">model.name</field>
         <field name="view_type">form</field>
         <field name='domain'>[('employee_id.user_id','=',uid)]</field> 
         <field name="context" >{'context_value':True}</field> <!--if required -->
</record>
```