# Closing Wizard on button click in OpenERP 7

Tags: python, odoo

I open the wizard from button in OpenERP 7. But when click on button **Compute** of wizard my wizard got close but I do not want to close the wizard on button click of **Compute** instead of my wizard close when click on button **Close** of wizard.
I am using OpenERP 7.

```
class test_pass_student(osv.osv_memory):
    _name = 'test.pass.student'
    _column ={  
        'pass_id': fields.many2one('pass.student', 'Passed'),
        'student_id':fields.many2one('student.student', 'Student'),
    }

test_pass_student()

def _reopen(self, res_id, model):
    return {'type': 'ir.actions.act_window',
            'view_mode': 'form',
            'view_type': 'form',
            'res_id': res_id,
            'res_model': self._name,
            'target': 'new',
            'context': {
                'default_model': model,
            },
    }

class pass_student(osv.osv_memory):
    _name = 'pass.student'

    _columns = {    
        'student_id':fields.many2one('student.student', 'Student'),
        'lines': fields.one2many('test.pass.student','pass_id', 'Passed students'),
    }

    def add_student(self, cr, uid, ids,context=None):
        lines_obj = self.pool.get('test.pass.student')
        for record in self.browse(cr,uid,ids,context):
            for line in record.student_id.scores:
                    if line.pass_score > 50:
                        lines_obj.create(cr,uid,{'pass_id': record.id,'student_id':line.student_id.id})

            return _reopen(self, record.id, record._model)

pass_student()
```

Shen S select first student check, if his/her marks greater than 50 then added in one2many, and then again check another student, same things repeat again.

Comment: thanks for updating the question, but your problem is still not very clear. Could you clearly mention in the question what you see as a result of this code and what you expected? Your code looks ok so far. You probably don't need the ``context`` and ``default_model`` part in ``_reopen`` (that was needed for the mail composition wizard but not here), but it shouldn't cause problems. Perhaps you can show the source of the XML view you are using, and a larger extract of the logs when the problem appears (it's better than just the error message).

Comment: I think this question should be titled "NOT Closing Wizard on button click in openerp 7" given that is what you want.

Answer (score 1):

The default behavior for wizard buttons (with `type="object`) as of OpenERP 6.1 (hence in 7.0 as well) is to immediately close the wizard pop-up. The method called by the button can return an action definition dictionary that will be executed. 
When you do not want the wizard to close it is usually because you have several steps. As multi-steps wizards usually have different form views, their button methods simply return actions to open the same wizard record using the next step's view (it could also be the same view if it needs to be displayed again).

You can find examples in the official addons source code, for example in the `mail.compose.message` wizard [modified by the `email_template` module](http://bazaar.launchpad.net/~openerp/openobject-addons/7.0/view/head:/email_template/wizard/mail_compose_message.py#L25), that uses a similar trick to re-open itself.

This [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13235220/openerp-context-in-act-window/13238243#13238243) and this [other one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10671025/osv-methods-return-statement) may also contain useful examples.

Comment: Thanks for your valuable reply odony. But when I do the same trick it give me error popup window **The server encountered an internal error and was unable to complete your request.  Either the server is overloaded or there is an error in the application** And at terminal **TypeError: ------- is not JSON serializable **

Comment: @user1576199: at that point you should edit your question and explain exactly what you did (including the code you wrote), otherwise it's very hard to help you ;-)

Comment: I edited the question. Hope this will help you,and sorry for my bad English and explanations :(

Answer (score 1):

For closing the wizard on button click add this code on view form xml:

```
<button string="Cancel" class="oe_link" special="cancel"/>
```

Answer (score 0):

no need to write separate method to open wizard again. You can just take object reference and return it with view id. for example.

```
def add_student(self, cr, uid, ids,context=None):
    model_data_obj = self.pool.get('ir.model.data')
    lines_obj = self.pool.get('test.pass.student')
    for record in self.browse(cr,uid,ids,context):
        for line in record.student_id.scores:
                if line.pass_score > 50:
                    lines_obj.create(cr,uid,{'pass_id': record.id,'student_id':line.student_id.id})
    view_rec = model_data_obj.get_object_reference(cr, uid, 'pass_student', 'add_student_form_view_id')
    view_id = view_rec and view_rec[1] or False
    return {
       'view_type': 'form',
       'view_id' : [view_id],
       'view_mode': 'form',
       'res_model': 'pass.student',
       'type': 'ir.actions.act_window',
       'target': 'new',
       'context': context
    }
```

Hope it will help you!

Comment: But when I do as you said, data on wizard goes to loose. I do not want to loose data of current wizard.

Answer (score 0):

I reply myself, in the wizard if, instead of button type workflow, I put button type object and there trigger wf works (no close), but is that the right path?

If someone need this is my object button event code (for my picking.import.wizard wizard):

```
def signal_import_load_2(self, cr, uid, ids, context=None):
    import netsvc

    wf_service = netsvc.LocalService("workflow")
    wf_service.trg_validate(uid, 'picking.import.wizard', ids[0], 'signal_import_load', cr)

    view_id = self.pool.get('ir.ui.view').search(cr,uid,[('model','=','picking.import.wizard'), ('name','=','Wizard import picking from CSV')])

    return {
         'type': 'ir.actions.act_window',
         'name': "Import",
         'res_model': 'picking.import.wizard',
         'res_id': ids[0],
         'view_type': 'form',
         'view_mode': 'form',
         'view_id': view_id,
         'target': 'new',
         'nodestroy': True,
           }
```